# Succinct vs Compacting de Bruijn graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am not that expert in the topic so please take that in your consideration while you are answering.

I was reading two papers
[Succinct de Bruijn Graphs](http://alexbowe.com/succinct-debruijn-graphs/)
and
[Compacting de Bruijn graphs from sequencing data quickly and in low memory](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4908363/)

I could not understand the **difference** between those two method , so can anyone please help me to understand the difference between the two algorithm? or suggest further reading to differentiate between both.

Is there any implementation in Java for the Succinct de Bruijn Graphs (the author wrote one in python) or any other efficient language

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A *compacted* de Bruijn graph is a different object than a de Bruijn graph. In the latter, all nodes are k-mers (of length k), and in the former, nodes are created by path-compression of the original de Bruijn graph. Therefore nodes in the compacted graph are of length k or greater.

Path-compression means, in this context, that each maximal-length path where internal nodes have one in-neighbor and one out-neighbor is reduced to a single node.

While I said that both graphs are different, they nevertheless *represent* exactly the same information (which is a set of k-mers), thus we often informally refer to the "de Bruijn graph" for either of them.

A *succinct* representation (for either of these objects) refers to a data structure that uses little memory.

I am not aware of a Java implementation of sDBGs, but there is on in C++: https://github.com/cosmo-team/cosmo

Comment: so I can conclude that both  compacted de Bruijn graph and non-compacted de Bruijn graph are the same except in the k-mer length. and both can be represented in succinct representation  to save memory?